# Does posting to a TXT file via PHP consume bandwidth on the client-side?

Tags: javascript, php, post

If I am posting data to a PHP file as follows:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "data.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xhttp.send("t1=" + data);
```

and that PHP file is writing the data sent to a txt file...
Is the user who loaded the page having bandwidth consumed by loading the txt file, or is it solely done on the server?

Comment: the user (client) who sent the request to the server to write the file consumed bandwidth, the server that wrote some data text inside a file consumed memory, so, no

Comment: The text file isn't loaded at all in the scenario you describe.